# Superscript 5 support in nexus 7

Tags: android, html, nexus-7, superscript

I am developing a web application for tablet (Ipad and Nexus),there is one requirement to display superscripts 2,3,4 and 5.
I have used unicode for this purpose.

Its working fine in Ipad but there is one problem with nexus7 that only superscript 5 is not displaying.
I have tried with many options but failed every time.

is this a bug/limitation in android version for nexus 7.

Plz suggest your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to user the superscript tag instead to see if that yields another result.

```html
here is a text with superscript <sup>5</sup>
```

Comment: there is certain limitation due to which I can not use this syntex..any alternative apart from this..